# ERROR org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Configuration objects do not support clean-up. Update aborted

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I am trying to integrate MyFaces JSF 2.2 Application with GCP, but I am getting this error:

> ERROR org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Configuration objects do not support clean-up. Update aborted

Is any configuration missing? Further this error doesn't come always, appears inconsistently.